# glsl uniform По дефолту или как проверить передана ли uniform переменная

Tags: c++, glsl

**Ситуация**: 
Пишу шейдер и делаю там функцию масштаба. Если масштаб не задан из программы, хочу чтобы он был единицей. Иначе при умножении на 0 масштаб будет 0.

---

**Вопрос**:
как сделать значения по стандарту в uniform, если значение не будет задано из программы.

---

**Ответ**: (Спасибо [HolyBlackCat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215103/holyblackcat) из комментариев). Можно вот так
uniform vec3 s = vec3(1,1,1); Просто создать примеренною и сразу же при создании задать значения.

Comment: Вроде в относительно новых версиях GLSL можно делать `uniform тип имя = значение;`. Проверяли этот вариант?

Comment: Н не проверял щас проверю

Comment: uniform vec3 s = vec3(1,1,1);

Comment: Работает спасибо, если сможешь напитаны как ответ и закроем тему. и другим будет ответ.

Comment: Лучше напиши сам.